# Parent & child records on same page best practices?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, odata

I have created a simple "order" form that has it's "order items" on the same page - built using mvc / web api / odata..

Just wondering how other people handle parent & child records on the same page?

This is how it currently works & I am wondering if anyone else has any better ideas?

1. When a user clicks on the "Add New Order" button a new "Order" is added with "Active = 0" (a temp record) & I display the edit form for the newly inserted order.
2. Users can then fill out the "Order" form & add "Order Items" to the order.
3. Once the "Order" is saved for the first time I then make the order active by setting "Active = 1".

There are 2 issues that I can think of by doing it this way:

1. Temp orders (orders that were not completed) will need to be deleted every now & then.
2. If a user edits an existing order & adds, edits or deletes "Order Items" from the order, this will modify the order immediately even if the user clicks on the "Cancel" button & the actual order is not saved. The issue here is that a user may think that by clicking cancel it will not save any changes (including the "order item" changes that they have already made - I hope this makes sense!).

Here is a demo of what I mean (note: the add "Order Items" bit has not been completed yet - but should be enough to get a general idea of what I'm talking about):
http://orders.mydevelopmentserver.com/myorders

Comment: Is your UI Design flexible to add a cancel flag to OrderItem? This way changes into order (add/edit order item) gets saved in DB immediately. If order item needs to be removed from order, user can edit the order and remove order item from order.

Answer (score 0):

1. you could create and modify existing orders only in view (on client side). Just prepare model to save. If everithing is ok and user click save, you send to your api filled model, and on server side update existing entries or create new one. If user click cancel, just clean your view model and don't send anything to server.
2. you can use temporal entries in DB. Your parent entity should have a flag or status indicating it is tempotal and preventing showing it in lists, and extra field to store origin entity id or null if new. When creating new entity or editing existing you should create new entity (or clone if editing existing) with this temporal status. Do your changes. If user click save, for new entity just change status to non temporal, for existing clone it back using origin entity id. And delete temporal after it. If user click cancel just remove temporal entity. If user close browser while in editing mode, you can handle onclose event to remove it's temporal entity, or remove it on next edit try.